# Difference between Integer(value) and value.to_i

Tags: ruby

Given a string object like this:

```
twohundred = "200"
```

What is the difference between doing:

```
Integer(twohundred)  #=> 200
```

and:

```
twohundred.to_i      #=> 200
```

Is there any difference? Is it recommended to use one among the other one?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`Integer(num)` will throw an `ArgumentError` exception if num isn't a valid integer (you can specify the base).

`num.to_i` will convert as much as it can.

For example:

```
"2hi".to_i 
#=> 2

Integer("2hi")
#=> throws ArgumentError

"hi".to_i
#=> 0

Integer("hi")
#=> throws ArgumentError

"2.0".to_i
#=> 2

Integer("2.0")
#=> throws ArgumentError
```

Comment: Note that you can specify the base for both, [`Kernel#Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) and [`String#to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-to_i).

Comment: Another notable case is ```nil.to_i #=> 0``` while ```Integer(nil) #=> throws TypeError: can't convert nil into Integer```

Answer (score 11):

From the Ruby [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) for `Integer()`:

> Integer(arg,base=0) → integer
> ...
> If arg is a String, when base is omitted or equals to zero, radix
> indicators (0, 0b, and 0x) are honored. In any case, strings should be
> strictly conformed to numeric representation. This behavior is
> different from that of String#to_i.

In other words, `Integer("0x100") => 256` and `"0x100".to_i => 0`.

Another example: `Integer("0010") => 8` and `"0010".to_i => 10`.

Comment: e.g. `"0x10".to_i` gives `0`, while `Integer("0x10")` gives `16`

Comment: `"0x10".to_i(16)` however also gives `16`.

Answer (score 3):

Let's examine differences between using the instance method [String#to_i](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) and the module method [Kernel::Integer](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer). First, however, let's embed the later in another method `int1`:

```
def int1(str)
  Integer(str) rescue nil
end
```

That way, if `str` cannot be construed as an integer, `Integer` will raise an `ArgumentError` exception, causing the in-line rescue to return `nil`. If `Integer` does not raise an execption `int` will return the integer equivalent of the string.

To round out the comparisons, let's also add a regular expression that confirms the contents of the string represents an integer before using `to_i` to make the conversion.

```
R = /
    (?<=\A|\s) # match beginning of string or whitespace character (positive lookbehind)
    -?         # optionally match a minus sign
    \d+        # match one or more digits
    (?=\s|\z)   # match whitespace character or end of string (positive lookahead)
    /x         # free spacing regex definition mode

def int2(str)
  str =~ R ? str.to_i : nil
end
```

As with `int1`, if `str` cannot be construed as an integer, `int2` will return `nil`; else, `int` returns the integer equivalent of the string.

Let's try some comparisons.

```
str = '3'
str.to_i       #=> 3 
int1(str)      #=> 3 
int2(str)      #=> 3

str = '-3'
str.to_i       #=> -3 
int1(str)      #=> -3 
int2(str)      #=> -3

str = '3.0'
str.to_i       #=> 3 
int1(str)      #=> nil 
int2(str)      #=> nil 

str = '3.2'
str.to_i       #=> 3 
int1(str)      #=> nil 
int2(str)      #=> nil 

1e3            #=> 1000.0
str = '1e3'
str.to_i       #=> 1 
int1(str)      #=> nil 
int2(str)      #=> nil
```

```
str = '-1e3'
str.to_i       #=> -1 
int1(str)      #=> nil 
int2(str)      #=> nil 

str = '- 1e3'
str.to_i       #=> 0 
int1(str)      #=> nil 
int2(str)      #=> nil 

str = '3a'
str.to_i       #=> 3 
int1(str)      #=> nil 
int2(str)      #=> nil 

str = '1-3a'
str.to_i       #=> 1
int1(str)      #=> nil 
int2(str)      #=> nil

str = 'b3'
str.to_i       #=> 0
int1(str)      #=> nil 
int2(str)      #=> nil
```

[String#to_i](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) reads digits (possibly preceded by a minus sign) until it reads a whitespace character or reaches the end of the string. It then merely converts those digits and possible minus sign to a `Fixnum`, which it returns. `to_i` certainly has its uses, but these examples show that you should use `int1` or `int2` if you wish to return `nil` if the string does not contain the representation of an integer.