# Checking if number is an integer in ruby using gets.chomp.to_i

Tags: ruby

I am planning to check if a given input is an integer. `gets.chomp` gets input as a string, and I convert it into an integer using `to_i`. If I input `abcd` and check using `class` or `is_a(Integer)`, it always says it's an integer.

```
x = gets.chomp.to_i
if x.is_a?(Integer)
    puts "It's an integer"
else
    puts "It's a string"
end
```

How can I check whether the input is an integer or a string?

Comment: An input is always a string. The result of `to_i` is always an integer.

Comment: You convert to an integer, then ask whether it is an integer. What result did you expect? Of course, it is an integer, you just converted it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Your problem

Since you're using `.to_i` to convert your input to an integer, `x.is_a?(Integer)` is always `true`, even when you have a string that does not contain any digit. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10093533/5660517) for more information about `.to_i`'s behavior.

### Solution

**Convert your input with `Integer()` instead of `.to_i`.**

`Integer()` throws an exception when it cannot convert your input to an integer, so you can do the following:

```
input = gets.chomp
x = Integer(input) rescue false
if x
    puts "It's an integer"
else
    puts "It's a string"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex:

```
boolean = gets.match?(/\A\d+\n\z/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be:

```
x = gets.chomp
x === x.to_i ? "It's an integer" : "It'a a string"
```

Comment: can you pls explain me how does this === things work basically this code work thanks

Comment: In this case it just means it makes sure the class of `x` is the same as class of `x.to_i` so if x is string, `to_i` changes it to integer and it doesn't match but a `to_i` on integer still results in integer so it passes